# Format error exporting to excel in List Labels

Tags: excel, export-to-excel, listlabel

I have a strange situation occurring while exporting a report into excel file type.
On 2 different machines (V.M.´s) i have a discrepancy on time type table column.
While in one of them the presentation is has expected in the other it messes the format of that specific column adding ‘tt’ to the end of it´s data.
Please find attached screenshots of the O.S. and excel result(I am not allowed too upload the lst and lsv files,sorry ).
Can someone please let me know what is causing the issue?

LL version is 21.

Thanks and regards,[image]

Comment: Can you check the system's default format? What exactly is the content of the column in the Designer? What's the column's data type? Did you apply a date format, or did you just add the date/time column as is?

Comment: Hello JBartlau,

Thanks for reply.

For that column i have selected ´Time->system seetings without secconds´. 
My S.O. is configured for UK regional format, while the second is for US, and that is the difference that is causing that ´tt´ in the end of the time data.
If i switch the regional settings to US and export to excel it will happen the same thing.
So, for some whatever reason US regional format is showing that ´tt´ in the end, and should not.

Any thoughts?

Regards,

Comment: We were able to reproduce the issue. As a workaround a custom time format would work. We'll investigate to find a solution.

Comment: Glad i was able to sent the necessary information for reproduction and thank you for the feedback.
Hope you succeed on that and wish you all well.
Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior will be fixed with service pack 25.004. A hotfix is available.